# Sonar - Rule customization - Markdown syntax issue

Tags: sonarqube, rules

When I update rule description using extend description, syntax to put text in bold doesn't work when text has less than 3 characters.

> example:
>   *ABC* give **ABC** and *WORLD* give **WORLD**
>   but
>   *AB* give AB and *A* give A

Is it something I did wrong or not ?
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there's a bug for short text in bold. [Ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9857) created. It's fixed in SonarQube 7.0.